# Adding fields to Pricebook object

Tags: administration, opportunity-lineitem

For each pricebook entry record there is a "List Price" field that is editable.  I am trying to determine if it is possible to add an additional field to the pricebook entry record.  I've attached an image of the record.  Basically I need to add another field of type number or currency "next" to the List Price field.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it is currently possible to add custom fields to Pricebook.

Ideas: [Add custom fields to price books](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000GuMPAA0)